# ESLint file in sibling directory

Tags: command-line, eslint

Bit of an embarrassing question, apologies in advance!

I am able to run ESLint perfectly fine from the command line on files in the current directory:

`eslint file1.js`

However, attempting to do so on files in a sibling directory does not yield any visible output:

`eslint ../folder2/file2.js`

The file exists and seems to be recognised as such, since attempting to lint a file that doesn't exist yields an error.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!

It would seem that ESLint automatically attempts to search for an `.eslintrc` config file in the directory of the file being linted, rather than the working directory.

As such, the lack of output on `eslint ../folder2/file2.js` is simply due to no rules being applied and thus the JavaScript being automatically valid.

Fixing this is tantamount to specifying the config parameter to point to the working directory `.eslintrc` when running the command:

`eslint -c .eslintrc ../folder2/file2.js`